# Rename items in BIM 360 using autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

We are upgrading our revit projects from 2020 to 2022 and our revit file names end with the version they belong to for easy identification ( xxxx_R20.rvt) and we'd like to rename all the items in the project to xxxx_R22.rvt. I have been able to gather all the items, their names and their URNs for a patch...
but the patch item throws an error saying :

{
"jsonapi": {
"version": "1.0"
},
"errors": [
{
"id": "5f1b5519-3118-4c43-80f4-97c412419acf",
"status": "403",
"code": "USER_NOT_AUTHENTICATED",
"detail": "The client_id is not whitelisted for schema 'items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel' access."
}
]
}

The forge client id does have access to the account and has been used to make many other changes...
I did try using the patch from versions to make the change to the name with no luck ... ( I receive the same error)

Any and all help is appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can not rename the file by PATCH item API, actually, you need to create a new version with the new file name, but you don't have to upload file again. Please try the following api:

POST /versions?copyFrom={tip_version_urn}

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "data": {
        "type": "versions",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "newName"
        }
    }
}
```

A new tip version will be created and its properties - including source file - depends on the copyFrom version you provide, usually it is the tip version.

Comment: I seem to be getting the same error... It initially said the folder was not found and after I input the "parent" data into the json (including the folder id) I got the same error as before...

Comment: Ok, now I saw the issue, the API I suggested only works for normal file under BIM 360 or ACC, like "items:autodesk.bim360:File", "items:autodesk.core:File", but does not work for "'items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel" unfortunately.

Comment: Sad............

Answer (score 0):

I tried Zhong Wu's answer and it works for C4RModels (I would post a comment, but I don't have enough reputation). These are the steps I took:

- Get the tip version using [this endpoint](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-tip-GET/).
- Create the version using [POST /projects/:project_id/versions?copyFrom={id_from_above}](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-POST/).

Comment: Thanks Chen for the info, sounds interesting, I don't expect this works for C4R models since the new version of C4R usually comes from publish, may bring conflict, let me check more and update here. Anyway, thanks for your input.