# Why is displayName not updated

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

Our webapp is showing the displayNames of the folder content of user's folders. We're doing a `GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents` for this and show the displayName from the attributes we receive from that request. We receive complaints of one of our customers (not all) that the name they're seeing in our webapp is different from the name of the same folder in the Document Management view in Autodesk Construction Cloud. This seems to go wrong on folders that they have renamed. It looks like the displayName that we get from the API is still showing the old name while the Autodesk Construction Cloud is showing the new name.

We tried to reproduce this with our own Autodesk Account, but we cannot. When we rename a folder, the displayName is showing the correct name. Our customer is however still experiencing this problem.

Why is the displayName of a GET foldercontent request for this customer not showing the correct latest name?
Is the displayName attribute the best attribute to use for this or should we better use the name attribute instead? Would the name attribute always show the same value as what is shown in the Autodesk Construction Cloud?

Comment: Could you help check if its Web URL is http://docs.b360.autodesk.com/ or https://acc.autodesk.com/docs? Sometimes, customers would be confused with BIM360 and ACC.

Comment: The web url says docs.b360.autodesk.com, but the logo in the left top of the header says 'Autodek Construction Cloud'.  The selected project in the header has a big B logo behind the project name which stands for BIM360 right? You tell me what it is, BIM360 or ACC.

Comment: If the web url is docs.b360.autodesk.com, then it's BIM360 without a doubt. If so, there was an issue with the display name of BIM360 Docs items a while ago. At that moment, our engineering team advised using `name` instead. But could you try renaming the file with the same name to see if the displayName will be updated together? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72391339/7745569

Answer (score 0):

We are observing the same problem. I was not able to find additional information on which attribute to use - so I am using the `name` attribute for folders.